# ElectronJs: How to show chromium toolbar

Tags: electron

I need to show chromium tool bar as shown in the screen shot below:

[image]
Is there a way to achieve this in ElectronJs?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/electronjs/comments/6i3vt0/how_to_get_electron_to_look_like_a_full_browser/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in address/tool bar in Electron, if you want one you have to create it yourself (using HTML, CSS, and JS). Here's an [example](https://github.com/steelbrain/Brauser) of a custom address bar, and you may want to have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1862) in the Electron repository too.

Comment: is *Brauser* integrateble in Electron app?

Comment: I don't see why not, it's just HTML, JS, and CSS.